# Subclass is not an instance of parent class in JavaScript when using class syntax

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

There are other questions on this website about almost the exact same problem, but they are in the context of transpilers like TypeScript and Babel.

A class created with `class <child> extends <parent>` does not evaluate to true in the expression `<child> instanceof <parent>` <s>as `TypeError instanceof Error` would</s> for example. But, an instance of the child class that extends the parent class *is* an instance of the parent class as well as the child class.

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

var child = new Child("");
var typeError = new TypeError("");

console.log(child instanceof Child); // true
console.log(child instanceof Parent); // true
console.log(Child instanceof Parent); // false

console.log(typeError instanceof TypeError); // true
console.log(typeError instanceof Error); // true
console.log(TypeError instanceof Error); // false
```

If `Child` extends `Parent`, then should it not also be an instance of `Parent` in the same way <s>`TypeError` is an instance of `Error`</s>?

Comment: `TypeError instanceof Error` is `false`. Where are you getting `true`? `Child instanceof Parent` being `false` makes sense, because `Child` _isn’t_ an instance of `Parent`; it’s a _subclass_.

Comment: `Child` is not an instance, it is a class and thus `Child instanceof ...` is not true.  `child` is an instance of `Child` and thus `child instanceof Child` is true and `child instanceof Parent` is also true.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I swear I've seen it or an expression that looks almost like it before.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I found it! The prototype of any typed array constructor is not `Function.prototype`, but rather `TypedArray`. So, `Int8Array instanceof TypedArray` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung See above comment about `TypedArray`.